# Bug in colaction for nested multicols environments?

Tags: multicol, bugs

I found this bug related to the `colaction` feature of `multicol` :

> The "column number indicator" doesn't switch back to 1 after the
>   "inner" two-column multicols environment ends. (The bold number should 
>   give the number of the column).

Is there a way around?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\printNumberColumn{%
\docolaction{\textbf{1}}{}{\textbf{2}}
}

\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}

\def\xxxxx{%
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printNumberColumn\par\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx
\printNumberColumn\par\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printNumberColumn\par\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx
\printNumberColumn\par\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx
\end{multicols}
\printNumberColumn\par\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx
\printNumberColumn\par\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx
\printNumberColumn\par\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx
\printNumberColumn\par\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx
\printNumberColumn\par\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx
\printNumberColumn\par\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx
\printNumberColumn\par\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx
\printNumberColumn\par\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx
\printNumberColumn\par\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Edited. But the idea was more to bring attention to this bug.

Comment: What is the bug you are trying to bring to attention?

Comment: @Myles - I *think* the OP is trying to draw attention to the fact that the "column number indicator" doesn't switch back to `1` after the "inner" two-column `multicols` environment ends. However, he/she isn't exactlly explicit; thus, the bug may also be something entirely else...

Comment: This file is maintained by the LaTeX Project team.
Bug reports can be opened (category tools) at
https://latex-project.org/bugs.html.

Comment: You are the first one I ever saw trying to next multicols.

Comment: I have reported the bug on the github website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never expected nested multicols that included `\docolaction` (but I must confess I also never thought about that  when I wrote the code). Anyway, it is just missing a single status write to the `.aux` file when ending aboxed multicol, so that is now fixed in commit

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/b087fd319cbdb6845e74b1ad2e136d6578adb4e1

and will eventually make it to ctan with the next patch release.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I used `colaction` only in the "outer" multicol environment. Anyway, since then, I found a better way and I don't need to use nested `multicol` environments. But, it's better like that anyway, and the bug was not a big deal it seems. Thanks again.